# Replace multiple occurrences of word with words from list using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file containing a list of several occurrences of  line

```
output = filename
output = filename
output = filename
output = filename
```

I also have a list of chronological filenames in a txt file which I would like to use to replace the occurrence `filename` in the order below

```
2d_slv_Nx.19800111.SUB.nc
2d_slv_Nx.19800213.SUB.nc
2d_slv_Nx.19800322.SUB.nc
2d_slv_Nx.19800510.SUB.nc
```

I would like the following output

```
output = 2d_slv_Nx.19800111.SUB.nc
output = 2d_slv_Nx.19800213.SUB.nc
output = 2d_slv_Nx.19800322.SUB.nc
output = 2d_slv_Nx.19800510.SUB.nc
```

Comment: In this example, you don't need the first file at all. A simple `sed /^/output = /` would do the job.

Comment: @Reqbisha If your input file also contains other lines than `output = filename` you should add some sample lines. Otherwise state in your question that there are no other lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   $ cat tmplate.sh 
    output = filename

    output = filename

    output = filename

    output = filename

    $ cat mkrepl.sh 

   while read fname
   do
     sed -i -e "0,/filename/s/filename/$fname/" tmplate.sh
   done < tmplate.sh
   $
```

Bash script:
read lines from tmplate.sh extracting each line into variable `fname`, then 
runs `sed` with bash substitutions.

Using `sed`,

- -i edit inline
- -e Expression:

Using a range from

- 0 to line with /filename/ on, (starting from line zero makes sed stop after first substitution).
- substitute `filename` with `$fname`

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to solve with `awk`.

In contrast to using `sed` in a loop this solution reads the input files and writes the output file only once and uses only one process. This will be faster for a longer file name list.

---

Assuming the file with the file names is called `filenames` and your input with the lines to be modified is called `input`, you can use

```
awk 'NR == FNR {name[i++]=$0;next} /^output = filename$/ { $3 = name[j++]; } 1' filenames input > output
```

---

Explanation:

The condition `NR == FNR` is true for the first file only. `name[i++]=$0;` saves the line in an array `name`, `next` skips further processing for this line. (It is also possible to use `name[NR]=$0;next`.)

`/^output = filename$/` matches the lines to be replaced, `$3 = name[j++];` replaces the third field with the name from the array. I use a new index `j` instead of `i` to start counting from 0 again.

`1` is an "always true" condition with the implicit default action `print`

**Notes:** If the lines to be modified look different in your real input, the script may not work. There is no error handling for the case that the file `filenames` contains less data than the number of lines to be replaced.